# Node.js app won't connect to MongoDB server

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I can't seem to connect my MongoDB to my Node.js app

This is the error I get when I run mongo status

```
2020-11-07T16:38:29.570-0500 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
```

This is my app.js code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const uri = "mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.9lxbq.mongodb.net/<MongNode>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("MongNode").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

Comment: Try to whitelist your IP address and check.

Comment: @AlexpandiyanChokkan That was the issue. Thank you